# How do you insert variables into a database table using PostgreSQL via C++?

Tags: c++, postgresql

I have a C++ program that inserts values into a database table. I can't directly hardcode the values in because the data is constantly being updated, but I'm really confused about the syntax.
When I try to do this:

```
l.exec("INSERT INTO course VALUES(cid, term, 'subj',crse, sec, 'units', 'instructors');");
          l.exec("INSERT INTO meeting VALUES(cid, term, 'type', 'days', 'time', 'build', room);");
          l.exec("INSERT INTO enrolledin VALUES(cid, term, sid, 'major', 'classlevel', 'level', 'status', seat, numunits, 'grade');");
          l.exec("INSERT INTO student VALUES(sid, 'surname', 'prefname', 'email');");

I get this error: 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pqxx::undefined_column'
  what():  ERROR:  column "cid" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO course VALUES(cid, term, 'subj',crse, se...

                              ^
HINT:  There is a column named "cid" in table "course", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

--
I was told that it's because I was inserting the literal string name instead of the values inside the string, and I'm confused as to how to insert the values inside the string via C++ while still using variable names.

Comment: Sorry, removed the mysql tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax of the used SQL `INSERT` query is incorrect. It should be:

```
INSERT INTO course (cid, subj) VALUES(1, 'subj');
```

You should specify table name together with columns to insert into and values after that. I reduced number of columns for simplicity. For a complete syntax of `INSERT` query check the [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html).

To insert values from your variables you can do the following:

```
int cidValue = 1;
std::string subjValue = "subj";

l.exec("INSERT INTO course (cid, subj) VALUES(" + std::to_string(cidValue) + ", '" +  l.esc(subjValue)  + "')");
```

[`esc()`](http://pqxx.org/devprojects/libpqxx/doc/3.1/html/Reference/a00196.html) function helps to prevent SQL injection attack.

Comment: When do you do single quotes upon insertion vs double quotes? cid is an integer, subj is a string? Which type do we put single quotes around?

Comment: @user5943954 Double quotes is used to specify [C++ string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal). Single quotes  required for a string value in SQL query.

Comment: Do you use the l.esc at the beginning of the last thing you submit?Like in this case, l.esc(subjValue)?

Comment: @user5943954 [`esc`](http://pqxx.org/devprojects/libpqxx/doc/3.1/html/Reference/a00196.html) should be used for each string value in SQL query. Please read the documentation [here](http://pqxx.org/devprojects/libpqxx/doc/3.1/html/Reference/a00196.html) to get the details about this function.